# SQL request very slow althought index is created

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a strange problem with some inner joins on my SQL - Server.
It is very slow although all columns that are used in the inner joins and in the where clause have indexes.

Here is my SQL request:

```
SELECT p.VORNA AS firstName,
       p.NACHN AS lastName,
       p.USRID AS [user],
       o.ORGEH AS OUID,
       o.STEXT AS OU,
       a.HolidayDate AS absentFrom,
       a.HolidayDate AS absentUntil,
       k.MessageDate AS actionDate,
       'holiday' AS reason
FROM Kondor_User_Activities AS k
INNER JOIN dbo.SAP_Personaldaten AS p ON p.USRID = k.Code
INNER JOIN Kondor_Users u ON u.Users_Id = k.Users_Id
INNER JOIN SAP_OE AS o ON p.ORGEH = o.ORGEH
INNER JOIN Kondor_UsersGrp AS g ON g.UsersGrp_Id = u.UsersGrp_Id
INNER JOIN Kondor_Cities AS c ON c.Cities_Id = u.Cities_Id OR (u.Cities_Id IS NULL AND c.Cities_Id = g.Cities_Id)
INNER JOIN Kondor_FixedHolidays AS a ON k.MessageDate >= a.HolidayDate
    AND k.MessageDate < a.HolidayDateEnd
    AND a.Cities_Id = c.Cities_Id
--WHERE g.UsersGrp_ShortName NOT LIKE 'UA_%'
WHERE (g.UsersGrp_ShortName < 'UA_' OR g.UsersGrp_ShortName >= 'UA`')
```

And here is my execution plan:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1018]='holiday'))
   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_FixedHolidays].[Cities_Id] as [a].[Cities_Id]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Cities].[Cities_Id] as [c].[Cities_Id] AND [RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_User_Activities].[MessageDate] as [k].[MessageDate]>=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_FixedHolidays].[HolidayDate] as [a].[HolidayDate] AND [RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_User_Activities].[MessageDate] as [k].[MessageDate]<[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_FixedHolidays].[HolidayDateEnd] as [a].[HolidayDateEnd]))
        |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
        |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([o].[ORGEH])=([p].[ORGEH]), RESIDUAL:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[SAP_Personaldaten].[ORGEH] as [p].[ORGEH]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[SAP_OE].[ORGEH] as [o].[ORGEH]))
        |         |--Bitmap(HASH:([o].[ORGEH]), DEFINE:([Bitmap1025]))
        |         |    |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([o].[ORGEH]))
        |         |         |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[SAP_OE] AS [o]))
        |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([p].[ORGEH]), WHERE:(PROBE([Bitmap1025])=TRUE))
        |              |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Expr1019])=([p].[USRID]), RESIDUAL:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[SAP_Personaldaten].[USRID] as [p].[USRID]=[Expr1019]))
        |                   |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Expr1019]))
        |                   |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1019]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(25),[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_User_Activities].[Code] as [k].[Code],0)))
        |                   |         |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000], [Expr1024]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |                   |              |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([u].[Users_Id]) OPTIMIZED)
        |                   |              |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Cities].[Cities_Id] as [c].[Cities_Id]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Users].[Cities_Id] as [u].[Cities_Id] OR [RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Users].[Cities_Id] as [u].[Cities_Id] IS NULL AND [RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Cities].[Cities_Id] as [c].[Cities_Id]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_UsersGrp].[Cities_Id] as [g].[Cities_Id]))
        |                   |              |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([u].[UsersGrp_Id]))
        |                   |              |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Users].[PK_Kondor_Users] AS [u]), ORDERED FORWARD)
        |                   |              |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_UsersGrp].[PK_Kondor_UsersGrp] AS [g]), SEEK:([g].[UsersGrp_Id]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Users].[UsersGrp_Id] as [u].[UsersGrp_Id]),  WHERE:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_UsersGrp].[UsersGrp_ShortName] as [g].[UsersGrp_ShortName]<'UA_' OR [RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_UsersGrp].[UsersGrp_ShortName] as [g].[UsersGrp_ShortName]>='UA`') ORDERED FORWARD)
        |                   |              |    |    |--Table Spool
        |                   |              |    |         |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Cities].[IX_Kondor_Cities_Countries_Id] AS [c]))
        |                   |              |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_User_Activities].[IX_Kondor_User_Activities_Users_Id] AS [k]), SEEK:([k].[Users_Id]=[RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_Users].[Users_Id] as [u].[Users_Id]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |                   |              |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_User_Activities] AS [k]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
        |                   |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([p].[USRID]))
        |                        |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[SAP_Personaldaten] AS [p]))
        |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([RevisionReport].[dbo].[Kondor_FixedHolidays] AS [a]))
```

It got better with the indexes but it is still very very slow when fetching all the data.
Maybe, someone has some hints for me how to get all the rows in a reasonable time.

Thank you very much!

Table sizes:

```
Kondor_FixedHolidays:         14,416 rows
SAP_Personaldaten:            13,001 rows
Kondor_User_Activities:    7,247,086 rows
```

Here is my execution plan, too, and I think the error is at Kondor_Users_Activities table although I have two indexes there. Maybe, a clustered index would do good there instead of an non-clustered index?

[Query Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNHTt.jpg)

[RID Lookup Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcGsO.jpg)

Comment: is the index used,could you paste the execution plan

Comment: Could you add visual plan? Easier to read.

Comment: have you indexes on kondor_fixedholidays messagedate?

Comment: Yeah. Seriously, give us a link to a .sqlplan file. Assumed and actual. Not only is it easier, it also has a LOT more information that this little piece you posted.

Comment: Hi, MessageDate is having an index, I can give you an execution plan as soon it has stopped working, it really takes a long time, I already thought about creating new statistics, maybe then it will be faster ... ??

Comment: `INNER JOIN Kondor_Cities AS c ON c.Cities_Id = u.Cities_Id OR (u.Cities_Id IS NULL AND c.Cities_Id = g.Cities_Id)` >> `INNER JOIN Kondor_Cities AS c ON c.Cities_Id = ISNULL(u.Cities_Id,g.Cities_Id)`. Your query isn't much better with that though.

Comment: Whats your largest table? `Kondor_FixedHolidays` and `SAP_Personaldaten` have table scans

Comment: Kondor_FixedHolidays is very small with 14416 rows, SAP_Personaldaten is 13001 big, there are far more bigger tables like Kondor_User_Activities: 7247086 rows

Comment: Before anyone considers trying to help.   This person stated in a comment to my answer that he aborts any answer after 10 minutes even though his query takes longer than 1 hour.

Comment: So... what is the purpose of extracting so much data? No human can make sense of that many rows. Sometimes really dumb business processes get ingrained and no one thinks to question them. You might be generating a data extract to load into MS Access or an Excel pivot table or something like that.

Comment: Wow look at your second screenshot: Estimated number of rows:1; Actual number of rows: **6,484,532**. There are a few solutions to this but this question is suffering from `shotgun response` where you're a bit overloaded. For your own learning experience I suggest you do some research on this situation - where actual and estimated row counts are different in query plans. Or someone could explain it for you but it might get lost in the information flood

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix1
ON dbo.Kondor_User_Activities (Code, Users_Id, MessageDate)
GO

SELECT  p.VORNA AS firstName, 
        p.NACHN AS lastName, 
        p.USRID AS [USER], 
        o.ORGEH AS OUID, 
        o.STEXT AS OU, 
        a.HolidayDate AS absentFrom, 
        a.HolidayDateEnd AS absentUntil, 
        k.MessageDate AS actionDate,
        'holiday' as reason
FROM dbo.Kondor_User_Activities k 
JOIN dbo.SAP_Personaldaten p ON p.USRID = k.Code
JOIN dbo.SAP_OE o ON p.ORGEH = o.ORGEH 
JOIN dbo.Kondor_Users u ON u.Users_Id = k.Users_Id 
JOIN dbo.Kondor_UsersGrp g ON g.UsersGrp_Id = u.UsersGrp_Id
JOIN dbo.Kondor_FixedHolidays a ON k.MessageDate >= a.HolidayDate AND k.MessageDate < a.HolidayDateEnd AND a.Cities_Id = g.Cities_Id
WHERE (g.UsersGrp_ShortName < 'UA_' OR g.UsersGrp_ShortName >= 'UA`')
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Kondor_Cities c
        WHERE c.Cities_Id IN (u.Cities_Id, g.Cities_Id)
        --WHERE c.Cities_Id = ISNULL(u.Cities_Id, g.Cities_Id)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for all your hints and selects, but it is still fetching rows. As soon as I have an execution plan I will post it. My SELECT is still running so thats why it can take a little bit longer.

Comment: @user3003944 just add `ix1` to avoid `RID Lookup`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect most of the slowdown comes from this join `INNER JOIN Kondor_Cities AS c ON c.Cities_Id = u.Cities_Id OR (u.Cities_Id IS NULL AND c.Cities_Id = g.Cities_Id)`. SqlServer is not good at optimizing `OR` predicates.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT  p.VORNA AS firstName, 
        p.NACHN AS lastName, 
        p.USRID AS [USER], 
        o.ORGEH AS OUID, 
        o.STEXT AS OU, 
        x.HolidayDate AS absentFrom, 
        x.HolidayDate AS absentUntil, 
        k.MessageDate AS actionDate,
        'holiday' as reason
FROM        Kondor_User_Activities AS k 
      INNER JOIN dbo.SAP_Personaldaten AS p ON p.USRID = k.Code
        INNER JOIN Kondor_Users u ON u.Users_Id = k.Users_Id 
          INNER JOIN SAP_OE AS o ON p.ORGEH = o.ORGEH 
            INNER JOIN Kondor_UsersGrp AS g ON g.UsersGrp_Id = u.UsersGrp_Id
              INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT a.HolidayDate, a.HolidayDateEnd, a.Cities_Id
                    FROM Kondor_FixedHolidays AS a
              ) x ON k.MessageDate >= x.HolidayDate and k.MessageDate < x.HolidayDateEnd AND x.Cities_Id IN (u.Cities_Id,g.Cities_Id)
WHERE (g.UsersGrp_ShortName < 'UA_' OR g.UsersGrp_ShortName >= 'UA`')
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot execute your sql because of some alias that are not working: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "x.Cities_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "u.Cities_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.HolidayDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.HolidayDate" could not be bound.

Comment: Just 2 errors now.                                                                                        Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "g.Cities_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "u.Cities_Id" could not be bound.

Comment: thank you very much, I will let it run, since I am not so good when the sql queries are "nested", I always have to ask what is going on. I only learned at university how it is being done without having so nested inner joins ). I will let you know whether it was faster than it was before. Do you think I will get rid of the 91% costs when I create a clustered index instead of an non-clustered index?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use the data from table. For instance, clustered indexes can make your table slower if that data is frequently updated. See this article for more [info](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/clustered-vs-non-clustered-index/).

Comment: If the query is still slow, try this to pinpoint the problem: (1) remove all joins from the query (2) add one join and run the query. If the query returned in a reasonable amount of time repeat step 2 again until you find the point where the query slows downs...

Comment: This I already tried: executing one join after the other, and indeed it took already longer than I was expecting it - It already has problems with the first inner join, and I am trying out to find why that is so. I will go through the execution plan, maybe there is something happening - Regarding clustered index: yes, I am aware of that, sometimes it helps, sometimes it makes it really slowlier - Your query came to an end now and it took more than 1h 15minutes, so it is as fast as mine.

Comment: So that's your problem... Your `Kondor_User_Activities` table has over 7 million records.... Try adding a where cause to filter out as many records as you can from the `Kondor_User_Activities` table. It's a bad ideia to inner join with 7 million records without some kind of filter...

Comment: @Frisbee There's no need to get personal. OP tested the answer according to what he expected to find. I agree it was wrong, as we were withheld important information about the problem, but he has improved.

Comment: @bastos.sergio: I will try or better said look whether I can eliminate some rows in the where clause. But this I have to clarify before. I overtook the query and the whole program so I am not quite sure what I can do or what is allowed but for me it seems strange to have all data from the last 8 years ( since this data cannot be used anymore ). Nonetheless, thank you very much bastos for your help!!!

Comment: bastos.sergio: I extended my original query with an AND clause at the first inner join: Now, the duration time was reduced to 28 seconds. But, whether I am allowed to throw away a lot of information, I have to discuss that with our specialist division. Furthermore, a colleague told me now, that we are having less disk space, maybe this is also causing some problems

Comment: It helps having lots of free disk space when running a query like that. But again, retrieving 7 million rows in one go is bad practice. The closest analogy I can think of would be trying to extract **all** the database data in one query.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I have to talk to the specialist division whether we can reduce the amount of rows. I cannot decide that on my own. The we are running out of disk space I was told some minutes ago. So, we must solve this problem, too. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

joins do not like OR
you can get rid of one OR with isnull

```
SELECT p.VORNA AS firstName, 
       p.NACHN AS lastName, 
       p.USRID AS [USER], 
       o.ORGEH AS OUID, 
       o.STEXT AS OU, 
       a.HolidayDate AS absentFrom, 
       a.HolidayDate AS absentUntil, 
       k.MessageDate AS actionDate,
       'holiday' as reason
  FROM Kondor_User_Activities AS k       
  JOIN Kondor_Users AS u 
        ON u.Users_Id = k.Users_Id 
  JOIN Kondor_UsersGrp AS g 
        ON g.UsersGrp_Id = u.UsersGrp_Id 
       and (   g.UsersGrp_ShortName <  'UA_' 
            OR g.UsersGrp_ShortName >= 'UA`')
  JOIN Kondor_Cities AS c 
        ON c.Cities_Id = isnull(u.Cities_Id, g.Cities_Id)
  JOIN Kondor_FixedHolidays AS a 
        ON a.Cities_Id = c.Cities_Id
       AND k.MessageDate >= a.HolidayDate 
       and k.MessageDate <  a.HolidayDateEnd 

  JOIN dbo.SAP_Personaldaten AS p 
        ON p.USRID = k.Code 
  JOIN SAP_OE AS o 
        ON p.ORGEH = o.ORGEH
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it seems to be much slower than it was before. What I found out in the meantime was that there are problems with the Kondor_Users_Activities table, the costs are 91% although I have all the necessary indexes there. The execution plan is below of the site.

Comment: Seems to?  Did you let it run?  You said it takes over an hour and you posted the comment 20 minutes after posted this answer.

Comment: I stopped it after some time, that is true - It should not take longer than 1 - 2 minutes since we do not have millions and millions of rows.

Comment: So the execution plan you posted is not from the query you posted?

Comment: the execution plan is from my origin sql that I posted above - it took me only so long to post it, all the other sqls that you and all the other guys provided me I already started but I aborted all of them after 10 minutes or longer

Comment: So your query takes over an hour. You aborted this in 10 minutes and concluded it seems to be much slower than it was before.

Comment: sorry, if I was not clear with my remark. I did not mean it as I said it. What I wanted to say was that my sql query is still very slow and I expect it to have it run within 1 or 2 minutes. It was not mean as an affront.

Comment: So in summary you dismissed this without actually testing if it was faster.  Not a good methodology for fixing performance issues.  Let alone rude.

Comment: As long as you do not have any other problems, Frisbee leave me alone. Maybe, the one hit with the Frisbee was not quite good for you. However, thanks to all the others who are helping me.

Comment: If you are aborting any answer after 10 minutes and have no accepted answer then just how do you know what is helping and what is not?

Answer (score 0):

As a blind longshot - no tables, relations, indexes or anything helpful, try this:

```
    SELECT
        UActivities.firstName, 
        UActivities.lastName, 
        UActivities.[USER], 
        UActivities.OUID, 
        UActivities.OU, 
        UserHoliday.HolidayDate AS absentFrom, 
        UserHoliday.HolidayDate AS absentUntil, 
        UActivities.actionDate,
        'holiday' as reason
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                k.MessageDate AS actionDate,
                k.Users_Id,
                k.Code,
                p.VORNA AS firstName, 
                p.NACHN AS lastName, 
                p.USRID AS [USER], 
                o.ORGEH AS OUID, 
                o.STEXT AS OU
            FROM Kondor_User_Activities AS k 
                INNER JOIN dbo.SAP_Personaldaten AS p ON k.Code = p.USRID
                    INNER JOIN SAP_OE AS o ON p.ORGEH = o.ORGEH 
            ) AS UActivities
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                UserCities.Users_Id,
                a.HolidayDate
            FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        u.Users_Id,
                        ISNULL(u.Cities_Id, g.Cities_Id) AS CityId
                    FROM 
                        Kondor_Users u 
                        INNER JOIN Kondor_UsersGrp AS g ON g.UsersGrp_Id = u.UsersGrp_Id AND (g.UsersGrp_ShortName NOT LIKE 'UA_%')
                    ) AS UserCities
                INNER JOIN Kondor_FixedHolidays AS a ON a.Cities_Id = UserCities.CityId
            ) AS UserHoliday ON UActivities.Users_Id = UserHoliday.Users_Id AND UActivities.actionDate >= UserHoliday.HolidayDate and UActivities.actionDate < UserHoliday.HolidayDateEnd
```

Don't know if I've hit all the column names properly, but what I see as a problem here is that the optimizer went berserk and because of complexity of your conditions said: "I'm gonna go one row at a time testing for each user activity to see if it matches all the other criteria".

My effort was to separate logical parts of query - in this order:
 1. create all cities that users can be - either directly specified or inherited from group (`ISNULL(u.Cities_Id, g.Cities_Id)`)
 2. create all holidays based on cities obtained from #1
 3. join those with needed user data from rest of tables.

Looking at this result - maybe it was even better not to create `UActivities` inner query but to join those tables from it to result of `UserCities`. To determine this, I really would need access - but you could do it.

Check plan before running. Should be a lot different and more balanced when it comes to reads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! - I will try that, too. I also thought about reordering my query or better said, I already did that ( but not in that way as you provide it me ) but it is always said that reordering can help but need not help because the compiler(?) is doing everything with its own logic - I got these error messages but I will try to solve them: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "k.MessageDate","a.HolidayDate","k.MessageDate",a.HolidayDateEnd" could not be bound.

Comment: Last line had errors - I've corrected them. Try it now.